# Matlab/Simulink To workspace, To file

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, sampling, simulate

I have a circuit with voltage source and 4 appliances
[image]

Simulation time was 0.1s. After the voltage source is one current measurement where i measure the actual level of electricity what i need to calculate the ele. consumption in KW/h .

The level of electricity is reflected in workspace or file in Timeseries.

This simulation describe a model oh small house with some appliances.

My question is how to get from scope data in exact time and write to file(like every 0.005sec - 0.010, 0.015 atc.)? 
[image]

I need only efective data from scope like the picture with arrows( i think it is always at the same time with the same distance). 
Or is there any other way to get their consumption?

Comment: I think is best if you export all the data to workspace/file and then get the specific data in the timesteps you want.

Comment: But if you Know the step time, just change "Sample time" to the secs you want. Just that